# WebSocket Error "Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, websocket

**Код:**

```
var WS = new require("ws");

var ws = new WS.Server({
    port: 8080
});
```

**Ошибка:**

```
[tonchor@PC project1]$ node server.js
 module.js:515
     throw err;
     ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ws'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
     at new require (internal/module.js:11:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tonchor/job/project1/server.js:1:72)
     at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит сама за себя: `Error: Cannot find module 'ws'`

Установите модуль ws (`npm install ws`) для его использования.

Comment: При установке пишет npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tonchor/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tonchor/package.json'
npm WARN tonchor No description
npm WARN tonchor No repository field.
npm WARN tonchor No README data
npm WARN tonchor No license field.